# home logical volume is not available after reboot

Tags: lvm, boot, rhel7

On a server with RHEL 7.2 it gets to emergency mode when rebooting. Looking a bit I found out that what happens is that the /home partition was missing and the reason was LVM:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/rhel/home
  VG Name                rhel
  LV UUID                6GB8TR-ih7d-vg7J-xCLE-A8OH-gmwy-3XLyOb
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                200.88 GiB
  Current LE             51425
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

In this emergency mode, if I do

```
  vgchange -a y
```

the volume becomes "active" and I can mount it and see the content. The problem is that after rebooting, the same problem appears...

1) Why is this happening?

2) If vgchange -a y is the only solution, how can I make this permanent after each reboot?

Comment: Please post the output of the following commands: `pvs`, `vgs` and `lvs`

Comment: also a copy of /etc/fstab

Comment: I can provide a screenshot, since I'm on the console and can't copy paste.
[link](http://pasteboard.co/131z1VBs.jpg)

Comment: also to copy and paste from the console, you just need to highlight stuff and it goes to your clipboard,

Comment: Still a problem? What's behind the volume group? Encrypted device, RAID, multipath? There should be something in journal - run `systemctl -a` and see if any of the units failed, check output of `systemctl status $FAILED_SERVICE`. Are there any errors in journal (`journalctl -p err -b`) ?

Answer (score 0):

in you fstab file add the _netdev flag to the device so the boot process waits for the phyiscal volume to become ready, and retries the mount.

so

```
defaults
```

becomes

```
defaults,_netdev
```

and make sure netfs is running on boot too

```
chkconfig netfs on
```

that should do it I hope

Comment: After adding `_netdev` it booted normally (not in emegency mode any more), but `lvdisplay` showed still the home volume "NOT available". By doing again `vgchange -a y` it fixes it and can use my "home" normally.

By the way, the command chkconfig failed:
`chkconfig netfs on
error reading information on service netfs: No such file or directory.`

Comment: If I add `vgchange -a y` to my bashrc maybe I don't need to care any more about this, but I'm afraid this is not the best way :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add `lvm` module to `/etc/modules` and rebuild the **initrd**, and **grub** (with `update-grub` and `update-initramfs`  on debian family and `dracut` on RHEL family linux)

This happens when during boot the bootloader gets loaded, reaches and unpacks the initrd filesystem and then encounters the fstab which tells him to mount LVM volume, however the lvm kernel modules are not present in the initrd environment (minified linux bootstrap to mount all filesystems needed to mount rootfs and its children) and thus fails during boot.